# a riddle involving some mathematics/hex

Tags: c#

I have the string as shown below that I'm reading from a database using linqsql. The string represents when a task can run in the respective application. I'm documenting the settings of the application and would therefore like to format the string in a human readable format (text). I need a method for chopping the string up and documenting which times its allowed to run. I hope that makes more sense.

3c8080080040040020020010010000000000000000003c

I've figured out the following so far.

The first and last 2 characters are indicative that we're using hourly increments (Hex 3c equals Dec 60) (We have another option to use 15 minute intervals but I'll not get into that now)

The remaining string is actually made up of 3 characters for AM/PM each day. I'll strip off the 3c and divide the days and AM/PM too.

[808/008] [004/004] [002/002] [001/001] [000/000] [000/000] [000/000]

Each 1 hour increment from 00:00 > 11:00 of the day has been assigned a hex value

```
800 = 00:00 > 01:00
400 = 01:00 > 02:00
200 = 02:00 > 03:00
100 = 03:00 > 04:00
80 = 04:00 > 05:00
40 = 05:00 > 06:00
20 = 06:00 > 07:00
10 = 07:00 > 08:00
8 = 08:00 > 09:00
4 = 09:00 > 10:00
2 = 10:00 > 11:00
1 = 11:00 > 12:00
```

So for instance, if we see Sunday's value [808/008] it would indicate that the schedule is open from 00:00 > 01:00 (value 800) and also from 08:00 > 09:00 (value 8).

Now my question is, how can I get this string from 3c8080080040040020020010010000000000000000003c to something understandable in a text / xml format?

I've attached a pic of the schedule as shown in the application

[image]

Comment: is this a programming contest question? What have you tried thus far?

Comment: What _is_ your question? Is it about interpreting the string, or about formatting the interpreted data?

Comment: @willem No, its not a programming contest question. It relates to the product I support daily.

Comment: @CodeCaster, its about formatting the data. As shown above I've figured out how to interpret the string. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your string into a 2d bool array like this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "3c8080080040040020020010010000000000000000003c";
        bool[][] weekSchedule = ParseSchedule(input);
    }

    static bool[] DayScheduleFromBits(int bits) => Enumerable.Range(0, 12).Select(h => ((1 << (11 - h)) & bits) != 0).ToArray();

    static bool[][] ParseSchedule(string input)
    {
        input = input.Substring(2, input.Length - 4);
        var chunks = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length / 3).Select(i => input.Substring(i * 3, 3));
        return chunks.Select(chunk => DayScheduleFromBits(Convert.ToInt32(chunk, 16))).ToArray();
    }
```

The array contains the data in the following format:

weekSchedule[x][y]

x index of day, each day has two entries one for am and one for pm. Sundays am schedule is x=0, pm schedule is x=1. Monday continues with x=2, x=3 respectively.

y index of hour. 0 <= y < 12

You can now further process your data and eventually print it out in a readable format.

This method uses the fact, that your hour values are single bits at different locations (examine DayScheduleFromBits closely).

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks a lot. It works great. I've tested writing to console, now I need to format it.

Comment: Hi Mario, i've implemented and it works well. Can you maybe explain in a bit more detail what each piece of code does to read and manipulate the hex values it finds. I would like to understand its so I can modify it and use it elsewhere. Don't  want go on SO and ask for code to be written for me each time. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Easy

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string decode = "8421";
            string input = "3c8080080040040020020010010000000000000000003c";

            DateTime sunday = DateTime.Parse("4/3/2016");

            for (int dayIndex = 0; dayIndex < 7; dayIndex++)
            {
                for (int fourHourIndex = 0; fourHourIndex < 6; fourHourIndex++)
                {
                    if (input.Substring((6 * dayIndex) + fourHourIndex + 2, 1) != "0")
                    {
                        DateTime tempDate = sunday.AddDays(dayIndex).AddHours((4 * fourHourIndex) + decode.IndexOf(input.Substring((6 * dayIndex) + fourHourIndex + 2, 1)));
                        Console.WriteLine(tempDate.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful, this does not work on all machines. DateTime.Parse, string.IndexOf and DateTime.ToString are culture-specific. Use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture for Parse and ToString and StringComparison.Ordinal for IndexOf.